# Interact with app launched from browser

Tags: ios, url, browser, safari, appium

I have an iOS app that must be launched from the safari via URL scheme. And I want to test it with Appium.

I managed to launch the safari and then click on the link that launches the app. The problem is, I am having trouble interacting with said app afterwards. Is it possible with Appium and iOS to send commands to an app that was launched from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to interact with safari using something like this

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//UIATextField[@value='Enter URL']")
            .SendKeys("www.google.com");
```

Comment: I do not want to interact with the safari. I've already managed that. Safari is launching an app using an url scheme (i.e. myapp://some/path) and then, I would like to interact with the app within the same appium session.